# SQL JOIN, GROUP BY on Four tables to get Record

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, join, aggregate

I have inherited the following DB design. Tables are:

```
auth_user
----------
first_name
last_name

staffuser
----------
phone_number
user_id

billing_customerservicebill
-----------------------------
bill_id
service_provider_id
discounted_price

billing_billmanagement
------------------------
creation_date
```

My query need to return Sum of discounted_price each user by month. Result are not accurate.
The following query gives me Sum up value correct but in-front of first_name is not correct:

```
select a.service_provider_id, first_name, sum(a.discounted_price) As total
from billing_customerservicebill a,
     users_staffuser b,
     billing_billmanagement c,
     auth_user d 
where a.service_provider_id = b.id
  AND d.id = b.id
  AND a.bill_id = c.id
  AND c.creation_date between '2017-12-01' AND '2017-12-31'
group by first_name, service_provider_id
order by 1



 My data show in Table Currently 
    service_provider_id | first_name | total
      5                      suneel      500
      8                      Ali         900
 Expected data is
service_provider_id | first_name | total
      5                      suneel      1000
      8                      Ali         500
```

Comment: MySQL or MS SQL ? Use `JOIN`

Comment: Tip 1: switch to modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax - easier to write (without errors), easier to read, and easier to convert to outer join if needed.

Comment: Tip 2: have table aliases that make sense, not a, b, c etc. E.g. `au` for `auth_user`.

Comment: can you post expected and current output sample ?

Comment: ok @Ravi
My Current Output is
24 suneel 5000
Expected Output
24 suneel 16000

Comment: The best approach when you're getting unexpected results is to create a dummy data set that replicates your problem and any edge-cases that could be considered relevant.  You can then give us that data, the rules you want to apply, the results you want, and the results you actually get.  This enables us to more clearly understand your needs and issues, replicate them and propose solutions that are actually relevant to your actual data.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @MatBailie if you don't know any thing not to write here. Thanks. please guide other people who can help this post.

Comment: @Zeshan - I've been here nearly a decade, helped thousands of people and have a lot of experience with helping people improve their questions as well as providing answers.  Your question is missing ***a lot*** of necessary information.  Without an example data-set to accurately represent your requirements, people are forced in to a lot of guessing.  You responses about getting the wrong results and wrong numbers of rows don't help ***until*** we understand the input data.  Please read the MCVE link that I provided, that SO wrote to *help you write a better question*.

Comment: @MatBailie Now check my question

Comment: @Zeeshan - That's a help.  Thank you.  I can see that `suneel` has ***lower*** than expected results, but that `Ali` has ***higher*** than expected results.  This ***indicates*** that the `JOINS` are perhaps being done incorrectly.  Please would you show the table definitions for each table, and sample data for each table for `suneel` and `Ali`.  That may highlight something as simple as joining on the wrong fields.  *(Again, please read the MCVE link that I provided, I really truly will help you get better answers.)*

Comment: @MatBailie No No you did not understand. in Total column record is not accurate place. in my case first_name and id incorrect but against name and id TOTAL value is not accurate place. Got it

Comment: @zeeshan - I appreciate that your English is better than any language that I speak.  It is, however, extremely difficult to understand what you mean.  To make it clear you ***really*** should read https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and then give example or dummy data for ***all*** of the tables.  I won't be responding to this for a while now.  I wish you luck in adding enough necessary data examples to your question to allow others to be able to rectify the mistakes in your query.

Comment: @MatBailie hahaha. i know my english is not good. but thank you for your time to understand my question

Comment: @MatBailie check my answer. i find mistake. ;)

Answer (score 1):

@MatBailie here is query i make.

```
select a.service_provider_id, first_name, Sum(a.discounted_price)
        from billing_customerservicebill a
             left outer join users_staffuser b
             on a.service_provider_id = b.id
             left outer join billing_billmanagement c
             on a.bill_id = c.id
             left outer join auth_user d 
             on d.id = b.user_id
        where c.creation_date between '2017-12-01' AND '2017-12-31'
        group by service_provider_id, first_name
        order by 1
```

Comment: `d.id = b.user_id` ;)  *(And the `LEFT JOIN`s make me smile too.)*

Answer (score -1):

b.id = d.id and service_provider_id = b.id
is auth_user id = service_provider_id?
mb you should recheck it?

try to execute and check the figures if tables connects correct:

`select a.service_provider_id, first_name, a.discounted_price
    from billing_customerservicebill a
         left outer join users_staffuser b
         on a.service_provider_id = b.id
         left outer join billing_billmanagement c
         on a.bill_id = c.id
         left outer join auth_user d 
         on d.id = b.id
    where c.creation_date between '2017-12-01' AND '2017-12-31'
    order by 1`

when you are done and sure with figures in fields then sum it

Comment: Use this Query
Select a.service_provider_id, first_name, sum(a.discounted_price) As total
from billing_customerservicebill a, users_staffuser b, billing_billmanagement c, auth_user d 
where a.service_provider_id = b.id
AND   a.bill_id = c.id
AND   c.creation_date between '2017-12-01' AND '2017-12-31'
group by first_name, service_provider_id
order by 1

Comment: @petro i check but same issue

Comment: @PetroZlobenko i run your query the result is divide thousand of record.My requirement is sum of record all month

Comment: @zeeshan I've provided you with code example to check if your joins were made correcly, as far as your question not related to technical issues but more logical I presume there is a mess in joining tables via ID field.

Comment: @PetroZlobenko THanks.

Comment: @PetroZlobenko the value show against user is incorrect

Comment: @zeeshan so as I expected there is issue in joining tables and as far as you are joining tables via ID field so you should watch carefully if all your ID's are corresponding correctly.

Comment: @PetroZlobenko yes my table join with ForiegnKey.

Comment: @PetroZlobenko you are correct. thanks i solve this query
select a.service_provider_id, first_name, Sum(a.discounted_price)
    from billing_customerservicebill a
         left outer join users_staffuser b
         on a.service_provider_id = b.id
         left outer join billing_billmanagement c
         on a.bill_id = c.id
         left outer join auth_user d 
         on d.id = b.user_id
    where c.creation_date between '2017-12-01' AND '2017-12-31'
    group by service_provider_id, first_name
    order by 1